# How to add multiple values to a dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to add multiple values to a specific key in a python dictionary. How can I do that?

```
a = {}
a["abc"] = 1
a["abc"] = 2
```

This will replace the value of `a["abc"]` from `1` to `2`.

What I want instead is for `a["abc"]` to have multiple values (both `1` and `2`).

Answer (score 188):

Make the value a list, e.g.

```
a["abc"] = [1, 2, "bob"]
```

UPDATE:

There are a couple of ways to add values to key, and to create a list if one isn't already there. I'll show one such method in little steps.

```
key = "somekey"
a.setdefault(key, [])
a[key].append(1)
```

Results:

```
>>> a
{'somekey': [1]}
```

Next, try:

```
key = "somekey"
a.setdefault(key, [])
a[key].append(2)
```

Results:

```
>>> a
{'somekey': [1, 2]}
```

The magic of `setdefault` is that it initializes the value for that key *if* that key is not defined. Now, noting that `setdefault` returns the value, you can combine these into a single line:

```
a.setdefault("somekey", []).append("bob")
```

Results:

```
>>> a
{'somekey': [1, 2, 'bob']}
```

You should look at the `dict` methods, in particular the `get()` method, and do some experiments to get comfortable with this.

Answer (score 28):

How about

```
a["abc"] = [1, 2]
```

This will result in:

```
>>> a
{'abc': [1, 2]}
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4):

- **Append list elements**

If the dict values need to be extended by another list, `extend()` method of `list`s may be useful.

```py
a = {}
a.setdefault('abc', []).append(1)       # {'abc': [1]}
a.setdefault('abc', []).extend([2, 3])  # a is now {'abc': [1, 2, 3]}
```

This can be especially useful in a loop where values need to be appended or extended depending on datatype.

```py
a = {}
some_key = 'abc'
for v in [1, 2, 3, [2, 4]]:
    if isinstance(v, list):
        a.setdefault(some_key, []).extend(v)
    else:
        a.setdefault(some_key, []).append(v)
a
# {'abc': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]}
```

- **Append list elements without duplicates**

If there's a dictionary such as `a = {'abc': [1, 2, 3]}` and it needs to be extended by `[2, 4]` without duplicates, checking for duplicates (via `in` operator) should do the trick. The magic of `get()` method is that a default value can be set (in this case empty set (`[]`)) in case a key doesn't exist in `a`, so that the membership test doesn't error out.

```py
a = {some_key: [1, 2, 3]}

for v in [2, 4]:
    if v not in a.get(some_key, []):
        a.setdefault(some_key, []).append(v)
a
# {'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: If you already have a list of values, `extend()` is **much** faster than `append()`. On the other hand, "there's nothing gained from using .extend() when we have only one element to append." (it is even slightly slower to make a list from one value to extend that). See [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119966/11154841). Thus, what you show here to add a list with more than one value with `extend()` and one value only with `append()` is best practice.