# Update Dictionary Key with multiple values for REQUESTS

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code:

```
dict = {
    "key": "0"
}
```

And I am reading some proxies from a file. Basically, I am updating `dict['key']` with every single proxy. Resulting in

```
"key": ['proxy1','proxy2'...]
```

But when I make a request, I have this:

```
for x in range(0,l):
    requests.get(link, proxies=proxies[x])
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "main.py", line 19, in (module)
request.get(link, proxies=dict['key'][x])
Key Error: 0
```

Doing `proxies['http'][x]` gives me  the `"str object has no attribute 'get' "`.

It seems that it cannot make one request with each proxy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, you are masking the built-in. You want a *list* as the value.

Comment: It sounds like you want your value to be a `list`.

Comment: What 'values' do you want to assign to all these 'keys'?

Comment: Make the value a list. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585920/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-dictionary-key-in-python) on how can you implement this.

Comment: What is `request` here, what is `proxies`? You need to provide more context. The `Key Error` message looks.. incorrect at best. Your traceback doesn't match your actual code.

Comment: Really, your question is now about something entirely unrelated, it seems. `proxies['http'][x]` is unrelated and something entirely different from `dict['key'][x]`, which is being used as the `proxies` keyword argument to a `.get()` method.

Comment: When you present us with error messages, you need to include the **full traceback**, and preferably enough information of us to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2):

You want a list:

```
dct = {'key': []}

for i in range(10):
    dct['key'].append(i)
```

This is simply manipulating the *list value* associated with the key. The dictionary itself doesn't really change, it is only used to reference the contained list.

Whenever you need more than one value per key, you need a nested structure. Here it's a list, but it could be another dictionary, a tuple, a set, instances of a custom class, etc.

Comment: @AndyG: corrected; I am using `dct` on purpose but tripped over the second use.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that but I guess I should've specified the context in which I am using it. I'll modify the question. My bad.

Comment: @Benjamin: whenever you want multiple values associated with a key, you want a nested structure. That can be another dictionary, a set, or as done here, a list.

Comment: @Benjamin: What you put in your question is invalid syntax, in any case.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the trouble. I've updated my question with the context in which I am using it in.

Comment: @Benjamin: that's not enough context; what is `request` here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid having to manually add the empty lists, use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list) # list if a nullary callable that returns a new list object
dd['var'].extend(range(10))
```