# Print a dictionary in python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have a file that looks like this:

```
5 John Doe 
3 Jadzia Kowalska
13 Heather Graham
44 Jane Doe
```

I read it in, split it up and save it up in a dictionary with the number as the key and a list as the value and each word as a separate string in the list.  I want to print each id followed by its name out to the command line but I am unsure how to do so since each name is a list of strings. Would I need a triple for loop? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import sys


filename=sys.argv[1]

#reads file into list
with open(filename) as f:
   filecontent = f.readlines()

names=[]
ids=[]

for i in filecontent:
    split=i.split()
    names.append(split[1:])
    ids.append(split[0])


d= dict.fromkeys(ids,names)
sorted(d, key=d.get)

for id, name in d:
  print id, name
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585920/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-dictionary-key-in-python. A key that has multiple values.

Comment: why dont you use pprint & if possible could you post the expected output, so tat it will be easy to understand the problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
for id, name in d:
  print id, ' '.join(name)
```

The way this works is that

```
' '.join(['first', 'last'])
```

Joins all elements in the list with an empty space as its separator. This would also work if you wanted to create a `CSV` file in which case you would use a comma as the separator. For example:

```
','.join(['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

If you want to print with a space between ID and the name, use

```
print "{0} {1}".format(id, ' '.join(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the dicts `.items()` and use string formatting and [str#join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to make the name.

`.join` takes an iterable (list of strings in your example) and concatenates them onto the empty string from which you call join on.

```
for id, name in d.items():
   print "{0} {1}".format(id, ' '.join(name))
```

should yield what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate lists into a single string.

You can also use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make it easier to build strings:

Both of these functions should also be available in Python 2.x unless you're using a very old version.

You also have an issue with how you build your dictionary, `dict.fromkeys` sets all values to the same value (the one you provide). You should use `dict(zip(ids, names))` instead.

And finally, the way you're using `sorted` is wrong since `sorted` returns a sorted *copy*. In this case you'll end up with a sorted copy of the keys in the dictionary that is immediately thrown away. Use `sort` together with `.items()` when iterating instead:

```
d=dict(zip(ids, names))
for id, name in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: int(i[0])):
    print("ID:{}, name: {}".format(id, " ".join(name)))
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason it gives me an error message saying it needs more than one value to unpack.  Why would it give me that error message?

Comment: It should be `for id,name in d.items()`.  The default is only to iterate over the keys.

Comment: Thank you.  Now it is giving me an error saying it expected a string but found a list...

Comment: There's an issue with how you create your dictionary, I've updated my answer with a fix to that

Comment: I also found an issue with your sorting