# Python dictionary (key1, key2) append more than one value to same key pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Trying to create a dictionary of two keys and having more then one value.

```
myList = [[('2016-11-01', 'USD'), 'ECB News'],
         [('2016-11-01', 'USD'), 'FED News'],
         [('2016-11-02', 'EUR'), 'Brexit News'],
         [('2016-11-03', 'USD'), 'Yellen Speaking']]

myDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d, value in myList:
    print(d, value)
    myDict[d].append(value)  #<<<----- Error here

print(myDict)
```

getting Error:

```
   myDict[d].append(value)
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Expected output: Append same key pair values together.

```
{[('2016-11-01', 'USD'): 'ECB News', 'FED News'],
         [('2016-11-02', 'EUR'): 'Brexit News'],
         [('2016-11-03', 'USD'): 'Yellen Speaking']}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple values to a dictionary key in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585920/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-dictionary-key-in-python)

Comment: You have a dictionary of dictionaries of lists. What you apparently wanted was a set of lists that are also somehow dictionaries? So yeah I think you're a bit stuck. Could you clarify with output that might actually be achievable?

Comment: Keying multiple values via a list: `[('2016-11-01', 'USD'): ['ECB News', 'FED News']]` is probably the solution you want. See the possible duplicate link.

Comment: @KS: ARe you sure you provided the right syntax of the desired output? Because it is not the `dict` nor the list. `:` in between doesn't makes sense

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `dict` object but you have mentioned invalid format as the required result. For getting the dict, you may use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(list)  # <-- You do not need `lambda` here
for k, v in myList:
    new_dict[k].append(v)

# `new_dict` holds the value:
# {('2016-11-02', 'EUR'): ['Brexit News'], 
# ('2016-11-01', 'USD'): ['ECB News', 'FED News'], 
# ('2016-11-03', 'USD'): ['Yellen Speaking']})
```

where `myList` is the list as mentioned in the question.

Comment: That worked, thank you MQ

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `2` above accepting mark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to use lists, so that they can be appended:

```
myDict = {}    
for d, value in myList:
    myDict.setdefault(d,[]).append(value)
```

Ouptput myDict:

```
 {('2016-11-01', 'USD'): ['ECB News', 'FED News'],
  ('2016-11-02', 'EUR'): ['Brexit News'],
  ('2016-11-03', 'USD'): ['Yellen Speaking']}
```

`setdefault()` method creates an empty list if the key does not exist yet or returns already created list so you can append another value

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this ?

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList = [(('2016-11-01', 'USD'), 'ECB News'),
      (('2016-11-01', 'USD'), 'FED News'),
      (('2016-11-02', 'EUR'), 'Brexit News'),
      (('2016-11-03', 'USD'), 'Yellen Speaking')]

myDict = defaultdict(list)
for d, value in myList:
    print(d, value)
    myDict[d].append(value)  #<<<----- Error here

print(myDict)
```