# Python dictionary with key value pair as value for a key

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I want to know how to create a dictionary with key value pair and value should have another values.

For example:

```
{key:{value1 : [a,b,c] , value2 : [d,e,f] , value3 : [g,h,i] } }
```

I tried,

```
a = {}
a.setdefault(key,{})[value] = a
a.setdefault(key,{})[value] = b
a.setdefault(key,{})[value] = c
```

then `a` returns

```
{ key: {value : c } }
```

For value last one added is only getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple values to a dictionary key in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585920/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-dictionary-key-in-python)

Comment: does ```key``` var change it's value?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
#create nested dict using defaultdict
a = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
#above line will create dict of dict where internal dict holds list of values
a['key']['value'].append('a')
a['key']['value'].append('b')
a['key']['value'].append('c')
```

## a looks like {'key':{'value':[a,b,c]}}

```
 #To read data iterate over nested dict
for k,v in a.iteritems():
print k
print v['value']
```

Comment: please add explanation as your post came in "low quality post" category