# Added multiple values to a dictionary key in python. How can I retrieve a specified value?

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code is derived from a past question on this site found here --> [How to add multiple values to a dictionary key in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585920/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-dictionary-key-in-python) This code allows you to assign multiple values to a key in a dictionary. I have tried several ways to use the `.get` method to return a specified list value using a dictionary key but nothing has worked so far. If this question has already been asked before please show me to the correct thread. I have not found anything on this so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
a = {}
a["abc"] = [1, 2, "bob"]

print(a.get("abc"))   # this prints [1, 2, 'bob']

print(a.get("abc"[1])) #this is an example of one of the things that I tried. Prints None
```

Expected output from `print(a.get("abc"[1]))`:

`2`

Actual output:

`None`

Comment: You mean `print(a.get("abc")[1])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to index the list obtained from the `get` operation, like so:

```
a.get("abc")[1]
```

---

**Why `a.get("abc"[1])` does not make any sense?**

`a.get("abc"[1])` is same as `a.get("b")`