# If key already exists in a dict, how to add multiple values to it (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'm looping through steps in a dictionary and pulling out a contact phone number and an id for each step, and put these as key/value pairs into a new dict: `contacts`

```
contacts = {}

for execution_step in execution_steps["steps"]:
    main_execution_context = get_execution_context(execution_step["url"])
    contact_phone = main_execution_context["contact"]
    id = main_execution_context["id"]
    contacts[contact_phone] = id
```

Where there are duplicates of `contact_phone` i.e. the key already exists, is it possible to append the value pair (`id`) onto the existing value, thus creating a list of id's associated with the same phone number?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585920/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-dictionary-key-in-python)

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) out... `defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save every value as a `list`. If the key exists, `append` to the list.

```
contacts = {}

for execution_step in execution_steps["steps"]:
    main_execution_context = get_execution_context(execution_step["url"])
    contact_phone = main_execution_context["contact"]
    if contact_phone not in contacts:
        contacts[contact_phone] = list()
    contacts[contact_phone].append(main_execution_context["id"])
```

###### Edit:

To add new keys:

```
contacts["example_number"] = list()
contacts['example_number'].append(main_execution_context["id"])
```

Or:

```
contacts["example_number"] = [main_execution_context["id"]]
```

Comment: Thank you! How am I able to add new keys into the contacts dict? At the moment when I try to add a new key I am getting a KeyError on 'example_number' when running the following:
contacts['example_number'].append(main_execution_context["id"])

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defaultdict`. Only key codes are shown:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
contacts = defaultdict(list)
contacts[contact_phone].append(id)
```